# siunitx S column does not align numbers without dot

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have a table that uses the S column type provided by `siunitx`. Unfortunately, if a number does not have a `.` it is not aligned properly. Yes, i could write `number.` but then the table will list the entry as `number.0` instead of just `number`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} \centering
{\small
\begin{tabular}{SS}
\toprule
{x}   &{x}   \\
\midrule
123 & 23.0e-5  \\
123.0 & 23\\
0.23 & 1.423  \\
0.23 & 1  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table with S column type]

Comment: You need to tell `siunitx` the `table-format` (at least with `parse-numbers = true`, the standard setting).

Comment: @cmhughes Dang. :) Queuing here apparently.

Comment: I think for a table like this it is a good idea to have the sample decimals for each number, so 23.000, 1.000, 0.230 etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution that specifies the `table-format` for each column; note that I also grouped `{23e-5}`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} \centering
{\small
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=2.3]}
\toprule
{x}   &{x}   \\
\midrule
123 & {23.0e-5}  \\
123.0 & 23\\
0.23 & 1.423  \\
0.23 & 1  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `table-format` works with exponents, too. For example `S[table-format=2.1e-1]` (close `\times`, overfull hbox for `1.423`) or `S[table-format=2.3e-1]`.

Comment: Works like a charm together with @Qrrbrbirlbel information!

Comment: To explain why this is the case: the standard `siunitx` alignment strategy is different from that in `dcolumn` and is based around the idea that numbers will contain a decimal part.