# Align along dot in tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Does anyone know how to align the figure along dot within the tabular environment? I would like the figures to be under each other sharing the decimal dot as a common point of alignment.

```
  \begin{table}[H]
    \caption{My table}
    \centering 
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \toprule
            &  A            & B         & C         \\ \midrule
    D       & 0.00      & +171.00   &  +135.00   \\ 
    E               & +233.00   & +123.00   &  0.00   \\    
    F       & $-240.00$     & $-20.00$      & $-1590.00$ \\
    G               & $-56.00$      & +68.00        & $-95.00$   \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: all of them have 2 decimals, why noch use `r` instead of `c` for `tabular` alignment?

Comment: You might also have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85229/27635

Comment: I initially wanted the head of the table to remain centered but by and large simply replacing c with r is ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use »[siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)« and its `S` column type.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{My table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
      l
      S[table-format=-3.2]
      S[table-format=-3.2]
      S[table-format=-4.2]
    }\toprule
        & {A}     & {B}    & {C}      \\ \midrule
      D &    0.00 & 171.00 &   135.00 \\
      E &  233.00 & 123.00 &     0.00 \\
      F & -240.00 & -20.00 & -1590.00 \\
      G &  -56.00 &  68.00 &   -95.00 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

More formatting options are shown in the package manual.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://www.stat.unipg.it/tex-man/ltx-68.html
:

```
\begin{tabular}{r@{.}l}
3&14159\\                        
16&2\\                          
123$456\\ \end{tabular}
```

produces:

```
  3.14159
 16.2
123.456
```